# I have a problem with my brush; it is working only to Z axis

Tags: sculpting

I have a problem with my brush. It is working only to Z axis, and some dots appeared on it. How could I solve it? Tried resetting brush but failed. [image]

blend link here

https://workupload.com/file/EkW9BzmZNM7

Comment: Hello, John.. It's hard to believe your share has to be 33Mb  to illustrate this problem? If you could reduce it, then you could share in a more conventional way for Blender SE, on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: sorry robin newbie here

Comment: Hello, @John.. no need for an apology, my comment  wasn't meant to sound like an accusation!  I'll have to watch my tone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about sculpting, but unchecking the <kbd>X</kbd> selection of both <kbd>Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Tiling</kbd> under the <kbd>Symmetry</kbd> section of your <kbd>Brush Settings</kbd> sorts the problem!

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer john, i dont know much about sculpting too